# DataGridView and BindingSource

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have DataGridView bound to the source:

```
BindingSource bdSource = new BindingSource();
bdSource.DataSource = db.Girls.Where(g=>g.BoobsSize == "C").ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = bdSource;
```

I want to display only 'Age' and 'Name' columns on DataGridView, but keep the other fields bound to the TextBoxes.

```
txt_Name.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bdSource, "Name"));
txt_Age.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bdSource, "Age"));
txt_Phone.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bdSource, "Phone"));
//.. other TextBoxes bound to the same BindingSource
```

How to do it ? Is it something to do with DataMember ?

Comment: Doesn't this work?    `dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "Age", DataPropertyName = "Age"});`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bdSource;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Age";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Name";
```

`dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false` should be before assigning DataSource.